# Selecting value from different schema

Tags: sql

I'm a complete and total newb at SQL. I know how to correlate data between tables, but that's pretty much it (and then, only if I have GUI...). I am attempting to write some automated tests for a site we are working on.

The project I'm working on contains 2 schema for users that register to the site. From time to time, we use the other, for "private" users. When they register, the users that go to the "private" site also go in the second schema.

Basically, during the writing of my tests, whenever I need a registration token from the default schema, I use this SQL command in my tests (which I write using Java code):

> select tokenValue from Tokens where TypeOfToken = 'REGISTRATION' and user_id = '48'

This works without problems, since the default schema is already specified elsewhere.

Is there a way for me to specify from which schema I need to select the token from?

Thank you.

Comment: It's database specific. Nothing to do with java. RTFM for your database server.

Comment: Why have two schemas for regular and private users? You could just have a "Private" bit column and update to true if they are private users.

Comment: @kan - Thanks for that.



Barry Jordan - It's what management decided, I can't do anything about it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tokenValue from [Insert Schema here without brackets].Tokens where TypeOfToken = 'REGISTRATION' and user_id = '48'
```

Comment: *sigh* Thanks. That was easy enough... I need to learn some SQL.